# How to modify the file on the fly while copying from one location to other in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I want to modify the contents of file while making the .jar out of it. To do so i am trying to modify the "processResources" task like below -

```
processResources{
    println 'process resources..'
    from('./dist'){
        into('static')
    }

}
```

Here i have some html files under "dist" folder which I want to modify while copying it into .jar
I have copied the file but didn't get any solution to modify the file while copying.

This is spring boot project along with gradle build tool.

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the nice documentation which covers  the file operations in gradle in great details- 
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch01.html

the solution to my problem is like this >>

```
processResources{
    println 'process resources..'
    from('./dist'){

        into('static')

        filter{
            line -> line.replace("old-string","new-string")
             }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle offers out of the box a number of options for changing files during a `Copy` operation.

I recommend having a look at the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files) and in particular the `filter {}` block, which can look at files content line by line.

Comment: Have gone through that but doc seems very much lengthy and couldn't find the exact solution that I am looking for.